# Guitar Amp Headphone OUT Jack. What Pot to use?

Tags: guitar-amplifier

With a Guitar amplifier's Headphone out jack, I need to attenuate the signal about 80%, adjustable. Would a 1k Audio Taper Pot be my best choice? I am attempting to use the headphone outs of my 2 15 watt amps to feed into an old cheap mixer board that goes into a Behringer box into my Linux PC. Without measuring yet, as I have no jacks or plugs and no resistors, I don't know what resistance to work towards. Someone told me 20 ohm, but that sounds like way too little.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this with 100% certainty, you need to know what is inside the amp. They typically have a resistor in series (R1) with the headphone output. My old receiver has 150 ohms, your amp most likely has a series resistor in this ballpark.

A low value pot could be used (without R2), but audio (log) taper pots with lower than 500 ohms are not that common, digikey has a 500 ohm log taper. With a 500 ohm pot, you need to add another series resistor (R2).

I would experiment with values of R2 until I got the desired attenuation.

If you already have a 1k pot, it could be made to work also, R2 would need to be larger.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzOaGz.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>